# Automatic adjust height on react-google-maps component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, react-hooks, react-google-maps

I'm trying to build a map application with react and google maps, I manage to create google maps component and use the map, however, when a navbar component is added I can't find a way to adjust the map's height to the space left without a scroll bar showing up.

The Navbar component came from bootstrap, I don't know if it makes a difference.

MAP COMPONENT

```
import React from 'react';
import { GoogleMap, withScriptjs, withGoogleMap } from 'react-google-maps';

const INIT_VALUES = {
  initialZoom: 10,
  center: { lat: -27.593500, lng: -48.558540 },
};

function Map() {
  return (
    <GoogleMap
      defaultCenter={INIT_VALUES.center}
      defaultZoom={INIT_VALUES.initialZoom}
    />
  );
}

const WrappedMap = withScriptjs(withGoogleMap(Map));

export default WrappedMap;
```

APP COMPONENT

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import MapNavbar from './components/navbar/index';
import WrappedMap from './components/map/index';
import './App.css';

const MAP_KEY = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places&key=******';

const mapStyles = {
  width: '100%',
  height: '100vh',
};

async function fetchData(callback) {
  const response = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/');
  const data = await response.json();
  callback(data);
}

function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData((a) => console.log(a));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <MapNavbar />
      <div style={mapStyles}>
        <WrappedMap
          googleMapURL={MAP_KEY}
          loadingElement={<div style={{ height: '100%' }} />}
          containerElement={<div style={{ height: '100%' }} />}
          mapElement={<div style={{ height: '100%' }} />}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you know the exact height of navbar you can use CSS `calc` property (docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)).

With calc property you could just set your map container to equal something like this

```
height: calc(100vh - navbarHeight)
```

If you don't know the height of the navbar, you could use flex to stretch the map container to remaining App space.

Comment: Where would I apply the `flex` property?

Comment: `.App` should have `display: flex;` and then size each child with flex property

Comment: Please make reproducible example on codesandbox and provide the link in the question

Answer (score 0):

You can nest flexboxes and define the height of the parent flexbox.
Here's my example.

`mapContainerStyle`

```js
const mapStyles = {
  width: '100%',
- height: '100vh',
+ height: "100%",
};
```

`APP COMPONENT`

```js
return(
  <div
    style={{ height: "100vh", display: "flex", "flex-direction": "column" }}
  >
    <div>
      <MapNavbar />
    </div>

    <div style={{ "flex-grow": "1" }}>
      <WrappedMap
        // your props...
      />
    </div>
  </div>
)
```

It's simpler to use Material UI Box.
`APP COMPONENT`

```js
return(
  <Box display="flex" flexDirection="column" style={{ height: "100vh" }}>
  <Box>
    <MapNavbar />
  </Box>

  <Box flexGrow={1}>
    <WrappedMap
      // your props...
/>
  </Box>
</Box>
)
```